# Do i need to write "sh script.sh" or just "script.sh" in crontab

Tags: shell, cron

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
...
30 05 * * * sh script.sh
```

or

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
...
30 05 * * * script.sh
```

is enough ?

Comment: if script.sh has a shebang and is executable, then you shouldn't need `sh script.sh`.

Comment: @MarcB Does "sh ..." means that i call a shell from a bash-shell and it affects the performance ?

Comment: you have a shell script.  one way or another, a shell HAS to get started to execute the script. whether that's directly from you doing `sh foo.sh`, or implicitly because `foo.sh` has a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, you WILL be starting a shell.